# Autoscaling azure roles based on Service Bus queue length

Tags: azure, servicebus, autoscaling, wasabi

Autoscaling Application Block from Microsoft Enterprise Library (WASABi) is a nice piece of software and it allows to change number of instances of your role based on the length of Storage Account Queue.

Can I use Service Bus Queue instead of Storage Account Queue? How do I define Rules xml in this case?

Comment: Yes, you can. See how's it's accomplished in Lab 7 in http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=28785

Comment: Why the hell was this closed as not constructive? Perfectly reasonable question... This is why stackoverflow is going to hell...